# Memory order introduced by atomic_exchange_explicit/atomic_exchange

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, stdatomic

I'm trying to understand memory ordering intoduced by `atomic_exchange[_explicit]` and wrote the following code:

```
static _Atomic int i = 123;

void *update(void *ignored){
    if(atomic_exchange_explicit(&i, 200, memory_order_release) != 200){ //1
        printf("Updated\n", stdout);
    } 
}

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &update, NULL);

    pthread_t t2;
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &update, NULL);

    sleep(1000);
}
```

*Question*: Is it possible the `Updated\n` will be printed twice (by both of the threads)?

I think *the behavior is undefined*. The UB is held even if we replace `memory_order_release` with `memory_order_acquire` at `//1`. The generated code is the same for acq/rel/acq_rel: https://godbolt.org/z/sFjcve .

This is because we have data race since for synchronize with relation to be held we need one operation is an `acquire` operation and the next operation is a `release` operation and the release operation reads a value written by a side effect from a release sequence of the acquire operation `5.1.2.4(p11)`:

> In particular, an atomic operation A that performs a release operation
>   on an object M synchronizes with an atomic operation B that performs
>   an acquire operation on M and reads a value written by any side effect
>   in the release sequence headed by A.

So the only way to make this code's behavior well-defined is to replace `atomic_exchange_explicit(&i, 200, memory_order_release) != 200` with `atomic_exchange(&i, 200) != 200`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrect. Regardless of the memory ordering requested, the exchange is atomic. Memory ordering explains how this read, write, or read-modify-write operation interacts with other operations, but the operation is *always* atomic.

Comment: I did not notice the `7.17.3(p12)`: _Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) stored before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation._. So it seems I may well specify even `memory_order_relaxed` and it would not cause data race, correct?

Comment: Correct. The memory ordering specifies how this atomic operation interacts with other operations, as the various memory orderings explain in their descriptive texts.